# Prometheus is not scraping metrics from actuator/prometheus

Tags: spring-boot, docker-compose, prometheus

My actuator-prometheus metrics are reachable under: localhost:5550/linksky/actuator/prometheus
For example, I am seeing metric named "http_server_requests_seconds_count"

I have set up my prometheus with docker-compose.yml:

```
services:
  prometheus:
    image: prom/prometheus
    ports:
      - 9090:9090
    volumes:
      - ./prometheus/prometheus.yml:/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml
    networks:
      monitoring:
        aliases:
          - prometheus
networks:
  monitoring:
```

and my prometheus.yml

```
scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'linksky_monitoring'
    scrape_interval: 2s
    metrics_path: '/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
      - targets: ['host.docker.internal:5550']
```

When I am starting prometheus, I can retrieve metric named "scrape_duration_seconds" and I see
that the scrape-job is correct:

[image]

But, when I am asking for "http_server_requests_seconds_count", I get no result.
Do I expect something wrong? Why do I have only this metric in prometheus, although the "linksky_monitoring" job seems to be running?
[image]

**UPDATE and SOLUTION**

I need to use a tls-connection, because each request for my spring-boot app has to be with TLS.
For this issue i have extracted key and cert from my p12-Certificate and made follow config:

```
   scrape_configs:
  - job_name: 'monitoring'
    scrape_interval: 2s
    metrics_path: '/jReditt/actuator/prometheus'
    static_configs:
              - targets: ['host.docker.internal:5550']
    scheme: https
    tls_config:
      cert_file: '/etc/prometheus/myApp.cert'
      key_file: '/etc/prometheus/myApp.key'
      insecure_skip_verify: true
```

No, it is working fine

Answer (score 2):

Your metrics_path in the prometheus.yml is wrong because it's missing a part of the endpoint. It should be like below (/linksky/actuator/prometheus)

```
scrape_configs:
- job_name: 'linksky_monitoring'
scrape_interval: 2s
metrics_path: '/linksky/actuator/prometheus'
static_configs:
  - targets: ['host.docker.internal:5550']
```

Comment: thx, it was a good hint, but i have still trouble. 
I got this error from container-prometheus:
scrape_pool=linksky_monitoring target=http://host.docker.internal:5550/linksky/actuator/prometheus msg="Appending scrape report failed" err="out of bounds"

But i've read, that if prometheus is in container and the app is running on the host, i need to write 
host.docker.internal:5550.
And my prometheus-metrics availible on: https://localhost:5550/linksky/actuator/prometheus
Any ideas?

Comment: now, i start a prometheus-container as a root, and i don't have any error messages from container anymore. But i still have no metrics :(

Comment: I think you're almost there. Localhost is indeed not working with containers running on the machine. I'm not sure if you have a static IP address on the machine but I have configured a local static IP address on my network and then put the target as ['192.168.1.201:5550'].